# How do I create column that will return maximum value of only certain groups of cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using Ms.Office Professional Plus 2019.

I have 2 columns:

[image]

What I want to do is finding maximum value for each ID.

For ID "123", the max value is five. So on column Result row 5 (where the maximum value is), it will show "yes" or other remarks (can be numbers)

For ID "456, the max value is 4. So on column Result row 8 (where the maximum value is), it will show "yes" or other remarks (can be numbers).

CASE 2:

[image]

I add 2 more columns: sum and status

I still need to see this data by the ID group. But if the status of the maximum value "not ok", then the result column won't return anything. Example, ID "456". For this ID, the maximum value is 4 (row 8) and the status of that value is "not ok". So the result is 0.

For ID "123", the maximum value is 5 (row 5) and the status of that maximum value is "ok". So the result column will return the sum of "sum" column for that ID:

`= row 1 + row 2  row 4 + row 5 + row 9`

`= 10 + 20 + 40 + 50 + 30`

`= 150`

That result can be shown either on the smallest value row (row 1) or largest value row (row 5), but can not be on every row.

Comment: What is you exact excel version?

Comment: I'm using Office professional Plus 2019

Comment: See my answer and feedback please.

Comment: omg thank you very much. I've ben looking for 2 days.. Would you mind trying to solve my case 2? I've updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try to the following formula-

```
=IF(C2=MAXIFS($C$2:$C$10,$B$2:$B$10,B2),"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much... I've been looking for 2 days. Would you mind trying to solve my case 2? I've updated my question

Comment: @matchbox13 Glad to know! Better ask a separate question.

Comment: Yep. I just posted new question. If you don't mind helping me, please do try to answer. Thank you..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77945147/how-do-i-create-a-column-that-will-return-sum-of-another-column-based-on-the-ma

Comment: @matchbox13 I will have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `MAX()` function and do a `Boolean` Logic calculations:

[image]

---

```
=IF(MAX(($B$2:$B$10=B2)*$C$2:$C$10)=C2,"Yes","No")
```

---

Or you can use `AGGREGATE()` function as well:

```
=IF(AGGREGATE(14,6,$C$2:$C$10/($B$2:$B$10=B2),1)=C2,"Yes","No")
```

---

Saw OP posted new question and then deleted the same within few, however here is what they might be trying to accomplish:

[image]

---

```
=IF((MAX((B2=$B$2:$B$10)*$D$2:$D$10)=D2)*(E2="ok"),SUM($D$2:$D$10*($B$2:$B$10=B2)),0)
```

---

Comment: thank you very much... I wanted to edit the title but then I can't re-post the same question.. :')

I've tried this formula, but the result is exactly the same with sum column. I can not post the screenshot. How do I show you my result?

Comment: oh wait. I can undelete the question! Hold on. Let me undelete so you can answer there and I can upvote your answer too there

Comment: I see. It's been a while since I use stackoverflow. I've posted the question there. So if you'd like, you can answer there too.