# How do I create a column that will return sum of another column, based on the maximum value of only certain groups of cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

I'm using Excel 2019.

[image]

I need to see this data by the ID group.

If the status of the maximum value "not ok", then the result column won't return anything. Example, ID "456". For this ID, the maximum value is 4 (row 8) and the status of that value is "not ok". So the result is 0.

For ID "123", the maximum value is 5 (row 5) and the status of that maximum value is "ok". So the result column will return the sum of "sum" column for that ID:

`= row 1 + row 2  row 4 + row 5 + row 9`

`= 10 + 20 + 40 + 50 + 30`

`= 150`

That result can be shown either on the smallest value row (row 1) or largest value row (row 5), but can not be on every row.

Comment: So how is this formula not working for you :`=IF((MAX((B2=$B$2:$B$10)*$D$2:$D$10)=D2)*(E2="ok"),SUM($D$2:$D$10*($B$2:$B$10=B2)),0)` can you explain?

Comment: I recreate the exact excel, so the column "no" is on column A, and so forth. And I just change the "," into ";" because that's what my excel use. Other than that, the formula is exactly the same as yours. Yet, the result is the value of "sum" column.

Is it possible to send you my excel file? or is that not necessarry?

Oh. this is my formula: IF((MAX((B2=$B$2:$B$10)*$D$2:$D$10)=D2)*(E2="ok");SUM($D$2:$D$10*($B$2:$B$10=B2));0)

Comment: What you are trying to say? The result column is your output right, if so then the solution do work. I dont see any difference

Comment: here's my result, with the formula visible https://imgur.com/a/8X8tpQb

Comment: Have you tried to hit the `CRTL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`?

Comment: OOOHHHH... NOW IT WORKS. Omg thank you very much... Imma check your answer. If there's anything else in stackoverflow I can do, please let me know. Thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posted the answer in other query of OP, posting here as well, though there is no huge difference between last post and the newer one, only a minor.

[image]

---

```
=IF((MAX((B2=$B$2:$B$10)*$D$2:$D$10)=D2)*(E2="ok"),SUM($D$2:$D$10*($B$2:$B$10=B2)),0)
```

---

Or,

```
=IF((MAXIFS($D$2:$D$10,$B$2:$B$10,B2)=D2)*(E2="ok"),SUM($D$2:$D$10*($B$2:$B$10=B2)),0)
```

---

Comment: Thank you very much.. Also, is there any workaround on the locked rows? You use $B$2:$B$10. I tried using B:B and then ctrl+shift+enter, but the result is #value. The reason I want to do that is because the data keeps adding up and if I use locked rows, then I'd have to drag the formula manual on each column

Comment: You dont want to use absolute reference? just make them absolute relative.

Comment: I just edited my comment above to explain better

Comment: Instead of using the whole range transform the data into structured references, that helps works more faster rather making the excel slow by utilizing the whole range.

Comment: is it the one where I define name to each column? and the using that name in formula? I've tried but still doesn't work

Comment: @matchbox13 here you can read **[MSFT Documentations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-table-in-excel-bf0ce08b-d012-42ec-8ecf-a2259c9faf3f)**

Comment: You could use this, but still i will ask you to use structured references : `=IF((MAXIFS(D:D,B:B,B2)=D2)*(E2="ok"),SUMIF(B:B,B2,D:D),0)` this works on my end.

Comment: thank you! Btw, I just posted another question. If you don't mind, I'd love if you check it out. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77946229/how-do-i-create-column-that-return-the-value-of-other-column-based-on-rank-from