# How do I create column that return the value of other column based on rank from another column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

[image]

For one ID, there are several occurrences as shown in column Count. Each occurrence has its own value and status.

I want to create column that will return last occurrence's status for all occurrences in one ID.

For example, ID "456" has 4 occurrences. On the last one, occurrence 4 (row 9), the Status is "not ok". So on the Result column, every occurrence for ID "456" will show "not ok" (row 4, 7, 8, 9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the `LOOKUP()` function, as it seems it would be suffice here:

[image]

---

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(B2=$B$2:$B$10),$E$2:$E$10)
```

---

Comment: would you mind explaining your answer? I know that the formula goes like this: lookup(reference value to find, reference column, result column). I tried your formula and change the "2" to "5" and it still gives the same result

Comment: @matchbox13 the formula tries to find the max number here it is `2` which it never gets for an id for eg `123` hence gets the last occurrence of the value with relative to the status columns. There is an alternative version, that needs to hit `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` however the one posted doesnt require

Comment: what does the 1/(B2=$B$2:$B$10) trying to do?

Comment: @matchbox13 have you tried to evaluate ? what does `B2=B$2:B$10` means?

Comment: yes.. I copied the 1/(B2=B$2:B$10) part to another column and all rows return 1.. And 1/1 = 1. But if I try to use 1 instead of 1/B2=B$2:B$10, it doesn't give the right result..

Comment: It won't that is what I have said. Because it tries to find the largest value which it can't and hence returns the closest value it finds which is the last occurrence by performing an approximate operation